# How to manage multiple tasks and background services?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parallel-processing, windows-phone, multiprocessing

[Background agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> An application may have only one background agent. This agent can be
>   registered as a PeriodicTask, a ResourceIntensiveTask, or both. The
>   schedule on which the agent runs depends on which type of task it is
>   registered as. The details of the schedules are described later in
>   this topic. Only one instance of the agent runs at a time.

What if I want many tasks simultaneous done in WP8 like, getting data from database and getting location information?

Secondly, if there can be only one background process possible, then why `ScheduledActionService` have `Add()` method.

I tried to add multiple projects of `Windows Phone Scheduled Task Agent` it gives following error.

> Error   2   The Project References
>   contain two or more background agents of the same type
>   'ScheduledTaskAgent'. projectName

How will I run parallel task simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on when you want the concurrent task to be run. If you want everything to run while you app is running, then you do no need any background task at all.

If you want all the task to run while you app is not running, just use one background agent and use it to do all the task.

Comment: So when I want `everything to run while you app is running`, I should go for threads? Is there anything like Windows Service in WP8

Comment: Not necessarily, for example the location API notifies you when the location changes so there is no need for a separate thread, just use the callback

Comment: +1. OK. For location API, or whenever I get events, I may not need thread, but say I want to get data from database and also I need to push/pull data from server, in that case I would have only option of thread.

Comment: Pushing / pulling data from server using WebClient is done asynchronously using a callback (or async / await). If your DB operation is really long, use Task.Factory.StartNew